# What is the alternative of placeholder in html for xhtml?

Tags: html, xhtml, placeholder

What is the XHTML equivalent of HTML `placeholder`.

Comment: What makes you think that the `placeholder` attribute doesn't work in *both* xHTML and HTML?

Comment: It does not validate with an xhtml validator. the xhtml does not have "placeholder" as an attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`placeholder` is new in HTML 5.

There is no equivalent in XHTML 1.x (which is the XML version of HTML 4.x)

It is, of course, available in the XML serialisation of HTML 5.

Failing that, you would have to fake it using JavaScript (which is probably best done by absolutely positioning a second `<label>` element under the `<input>` which you set to have a transparent background colour unless it has a value or the focus).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I kept assuming there was an equivalent or alternative directly using only xhtml. I shall try using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I did a experiment to simulate the placeholder using xhtml+js+css as happen on HTML5 placeholder property.

**xhtml:**

```
 <input id="textbox-obj" type="text" class="search-txt" data-placeholder="Search" title="Search something here">
```

**Javascript (jquery):**

```
 //Function to place the textbox cursor to the begining
 function moveCursorToStart(el) {
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number") {
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = 0;
    } else if (typeof el.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        el.focus();
        var range = el.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.select();
    }
 }

 function initSearchTextPlaceholder(textBox) {
    textBox.focus(function() {
      if( $(this).val() == $(this).attr('data-placeholder') ) {
        moveCursorToStart(this);

        // To fix Chrome's bug
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            moveCursorToStart(this);
        }, 1);
      }
    }).blur(function() {
      if( $(this).val() == $(this).attr('data-placeholder') || $(this).val() == '' ) {
        $(this).addClass('placeholder').val($(this).attr('data-placeholder'));
      }
    }).on('keypress', function() {
      if( $(this).val() == $(this).attr('data-placeholder') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('placeholder').val('');
      }
    }
    ).blur();
 }

 initSearchTextPlaceholder($("#textbox-obj"));
```

**CSS**

```
.search-txt {
    color: #333;
}
.search-txt.placeholder {
    color: #8d8d8d;
}
```